# JSON.parse или eval ?

Tags: json, javascript

Данные с сервера приходят в виде json массива объектов.

Через чего лучше его превратить в массив объектов, через JSON.parse или eval ?

В чем их отличие?

JSON.parse стандартный метод? есть в спецификации?

Если кто знает статейку, скиньте, буду благодарен!

Comment: Используй евал

Comment: но ведь [гугл][1] не отменяли?
   [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: @S9ZAAAA, ну наконец-то вы успокоились. Или я что-то пропустил?)

Comment: @SuperCreeper этот вопрос - одна из причин.

Answer (score 12):

Никогда не выполняйте `eval` над строкой, которую вы не контролируете. В этой строке может содержаться что угодно, не обязательно данные.

Eval is [evil](https://ericlippert.com/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/).

Comment: @VladD, я бы не был столь категоричен. Выделил бы *"которую вы не контролируете"*.

Представьте, Вы делаете распределенную программу. Иногда довольно естественно передать из одной ее части в другую свежесгенеренный код с данными, который исполняется в текущем окружении именно другой части. Т.е. eval.

Ну, или более приземленно, просто вспомните .bashrc и т.п.

Конечно,  совсем уж забывать о безопасности не нужно.

Comment: @avp: Как мне кажется, такой подход не вполне хорош. Если вы не можете быть уверенным, что код не отошлёт пароль пользователя злоумышленнику, не сотрёт записи из базы данных, не совершит банковскую транзакцию от имени пользователя — стоит не доверять коду. Точно так же, как вы не запускаете на своём компьютере через sudo [первый попавшийся пример из интернета](http://mydebianblog.blogspot.com/2008/04/unix.html).

Comment: @VladD, вот sl из этих примеров мне действительно понравился!!!

--

А если быть последовательным противником eval, то надо вообще отказаться от js на всех страницах (он ведь через eval и запускается в браузере).

Comment: @avp: Хм. Смотрите, как я думаю про это. Когда я сообщаю пароль сайту, я доверяю ему. Если сайт выполняет чужой код, он доверяет этому коду, то есть, его источнику — а значит, и я, не зная об этом, доверяю свои пароли этому источнику. Честно ли со стороны сайта злоупотреблять моим доверием? Зависит от того, _действительно_ ли сайт доверяет источнику, или просто из-за лени программистов, применивших `eval` там, где без него можно было бы обойтись.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже сказали, если можно обойтись без `eval`, значит нужно обойтись. Если же никак не обойтись, то лучше тогда так:

```
var data = (new Function('return '+JSONData))()
```

Таким образом вредоносный код, переданный вместо `JSON` по крайней мере не будет иметь доступ к глобальным переменным.